# Static class/values available only for current connection/user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have Asp.NET core 2.I'm using a static class to keep some info available about current user (accessible in all controllers,etc),but seem to me,sometimes,static values from a user are visible to another.how to make static values available only for current connection/user?

```
  public static class globalVariables
    {

        public static string Value1;

        public static string getUserValue1()..
        {
           ....
        }
......
```

I'm using it that way:

```
globalVariables.getUserValue1(..)
```

thanks

Comment: How have you configured your server on how many instances and worker thread you are using? How is your application configured to handle multiple service requests?

Comment: I use default.I've set nothing special

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the configuration you are using for your server. If you handle multiple service requests in the same instance is no wonder you can access the data because that's the point of `static`. If you use different instances for each request then they can't access the data from a different process. Without the configuration you are using it's just guessing.

Comment: Keep in mind that html is stateless. You cannot depend on the assumption that a request will receive the same process instance on the server. You need some persistence layer. I think storing state in a cookie on the users device could suit your needs

Comment: Best advice here: avoid `static`. You have cookies, a MemoryCache , you could enable Session, ...

Comment: the best way is avoid static and think about Depency Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem solved using sessions,thanks to Henk and also info from that [link](https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/):

Open up startup.cs and add the AddSession() and AddDistributedMemoryCache() lines to the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
// Add MVC services to the services container.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
services.AddSession();
```

Next, we’ll tell ASP.NET Core to use a Memory Cache to store the session data. Add the UseSession() call below to the Configure(IApplicationBulider app, ...)

```
// IMPORTANT: This session call MUST go before UseMvc()
app.UseSession();

// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Where’s the Session variable gone?
Relax it’s still there, just not where you think it is. You can now find the session object by using HttpContext.Session. HttpContext is just the current HttpContext exposed to you by the Controller class.

If you’re not in a controller, you can still access the HttpContext by injecting IHttpContextAccessor.

Let’s go ahead and add sessions to our Home Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; // Needed for the SetString and GetString extension methods

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "Ben Rules!");
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");

        return View();
    }
}
```

You’ll see the Index() and About() methods making use of the Session object. It’s pretty easy here, just use one of the Set() methods to store your data and one of the Get() methods to retrieve it.

Just for fun, let’s inject the context into a random class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public SomeOtherClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void TestSet()
    {
        _session.SetString("Test", "Ben Rules!");
    }

    public void TestGet()
    {
        var message = _session.GetString("Test");
    }
}
```